# How do I add link targets to Ruby mkmf?

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

In [my Ruby extension](https://github.com/matheusmoreira/mg), the code is organized into directories, with `extconf.rb` sitting at the root of the tree among the main library files.

The problem with this setup is that all files inside directories are not being linked against my library. `mkmf` doesn't seem to consider them at all.

How do I manually add them as link targets in `mkmf`?

Better question would be: is there a more flexible build system for Ruby that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but have you tried `dir_config()` ?

See the notes for mkfm.rb: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/Object.html#method-i-dir_config